# Webex Application on Android does not bypass Do Not Disturb

Tags: samsung, android-12, do-not-disturb

I'm using a Samsung Galaxy Note 20 Ultra 5G on Android 12, One UI 4.1.

Where I work, we use Webex for our phone system.  Every so often, I go on call.  My cell number gets added as part of an on call hunt group.  When I'm not on call, someone else gets added.

Because the Webex app's call sound is really not very alerting, I like to have my cell's phone app ring, in addition to the Webex app (I have a much more alerting sound for the phone app).

When I'm on call, I need the Webex app to bypass my do not disturb so it wakes me up in the middle of the night.  It does not.  Consequently, I've had to get creative with a bunch of other settings that really screw around with how my phone rings.  Ideally, what I want is for my phone app on my cell to ring whenever my desk phone (a softphone on my workstation at work) rings.  When I'm on call, setting Remote Office in the Webex app to "on" with my cell number seems to force my cell and my desk to ring at the same time as the phone app and the Webex app.  When I'm not on call, this same setting seems to force calls to my work number to go direct to my cell and direct to voicemail.  The cell will ring once briefly.  Webex doesn't even ring.

To deal with this, I have to disable all my other app notifications and leave do not disturb turned off overnight.  This is less than ideal.

What do I do?  Life seems like it would work properly if Do Not Disturb settings were respected.  I am set to allow the Webex app through Do Not Disturb in Android and while the alert shows on the screen, it doesn't make any noise or vibration - which makes me believe that it's not actually bypassing Do Not Disturb.

Comment: In my personal experience, you can add specific contacts, to a list of contacts that CAN contact you while Do Not Disturb is enabled. Suggested by someone who is “on call” the majority of the year

Comment: You would think, but no.  The number that is used incoming changes depending on who calls.  I can't just allow a whole bank of numbers through my do not disturb.  Namely because I can't know who is going to be calling from whatever number.